# "Requested Resource does not exist" with lightning-record-form in experience cloud page

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, experience-cloud

I'm using a lightning-record-form to display a custom object:

```
<template lwc:if={expedienteId}>
    <lightning-record-form record-id={expedienteId} object-api-name="Expediente_de_Negativos__c" mode="read-only" layout-type="Full" density="comfy" columns="1"></lightning-record-form>
</template>
```

expedienteId is not undefined or null, and I get the following error:

[image]

The logged in user's profile has read and edit access to the object.
The following stackexchange post also asks about the same error , but had no answer: [lightning-record-edit-form component used in Community returns error: "The requested resource does not exist"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275872/lightning-record-edit-form-component-used-in-community-returns-error-the-reque)

The weird thing is there is another LWC in that experience cloud site, that also uses a record-form for another custom object and it works fine. No differences in code or permissions. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is the `expedienteId` a valid ID of a record of the given object type (`Expediente_de_Negativos__c`)? Does the contextual user have sharing access to that record?

Comment: @PhilW Hey phil! so yeah, the problem was because of sharing rules. The logged in user had to be a contact of the account associated with the record and I didn't know that (because of badly defined requirement). Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when you try to save an update to a lookup field using the ID of a record to which the contextual user doesn't have sharing access.